# Helm Hooks to Ingress resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have a requirement where I want to apply helm hooks to ingress resource which in turn create secrets in cluster. We have a custom controller that reads annotations and create secrets if ingress annotations are there. Hence want to add hooks to ingress resource.

By reading the docs and command `helm get hooks release-name` It didn't list me the hook I defined in ingress resource. Can I put hooks in ingress ?

Comment: A Helm hook is just a Kubernetes resources that gets installed and uninstalled at a specific point in the installation sequence.  It's usually a Job but it doesn't strictly need to be.  In principle you should be able to add the [hook annotations](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) to an Ingress resources.  What have you written already, and what happens if you add the annotations?

Comment: When I used it with Ingress it didn't made any difference and helm upgrade passed just fine, My use case was to deploy ingress first and rest others so I only used weight as helm hook but it made no difference so I guess this isn't supported on the resource

Comment: @vgdub Did you check which resource was installed first? Did it install the ingress first.
Of course helm upgrade will pass just fine. In your custom controller are you watching the Ingress Resource types to read annotations?